# converting VBA array to a JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, vba

I am struggling to convert an array in VBA to JSON. Most of the info on the internet is for the reverse. Has anyone done this before? Do you still have the function?

I need to take an associative array in VBA (excel) and convert it to JSON so I can use it in javascript on my site.

Structure

```
cars ['BMW'][0]['model'] = 'Series 5'
cars ['BMW'][0]['year'] = 2000
cars ['BMW'][0]['shape'] = 'hatch'
cars ['BMW'][0]['doors'] = 5
cars ['BMW'][1]['model'] = 'Series 3'
......
```

Comment: What is the storage mechanic for that data? cells on a sheet? a UDT array? dictionary?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?  How it should look, or how to loop through your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript array of object literals:

```
   [{make:'BMW',model:'Series 5',year:2000,shape:'hatch',doors:5},
    {make:'BMW',model:'Series 3',year:2001,shape:'hatch',doors:5}]
```

Possible JSON equivalent:

```
    {"cars":[{"make":"BMW","model":"Series 5","year":2000,"shape":"hatch","doors":5},
     {"make":"BMW","model":"Series 3","year":2001,"shape":"hatch","doors":5}]}
```

Unless you're asking a different question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an Excel Spreadsheet with rows and columns, your JSON structure will look something like.

```
[[r1c1, r1c2, r1c3, r1c4, r1c5],
 [r2c1, r2c2, r2c3, r2c4, r2c5],
 [r3c1, r3c2, r3c3, r3c4, r3c5],
 [r4c1, r4c2, r4c3, r4c4, r4c5],
 [r5c1, r5c2, r5c3, r5c4, r5c5]]
```

This assumes you have 5 rows and 5 columns. (r1c1 is the cell at row1,column1)